# PHP How to keep radio button state to the next page

Tags: php, forms, radio-button

I made a form with radio buttons. How can I preserve it's state after a user picked a choice? Then same form will show again in the next page and the radio button that the user picked is enabled.

//page1.html

```
<form method="post" action="page2.html">
    <p>
      <input type="radio" name="q1" value="A" />
      A. <br />
      <input type="radio" name="q1" value="B" />
      B. <br />
      <input type="radio" name="q1" value="C" />
      C. <br />
      <input type="radio" name="q1" value="D" />
      D. 
    <p>
      <input type="submit" name="action" value="Enter" />
    </p>
  </form>
```

Comment: If you are using `action` then that would be handled server-side.  The server would read the information and spit out a form with pre-selected elements. This requires programming in something other than HTML, such as PHP, Perl, Python, C, Node.JS, etc...

Comment: This really depends on how you have set up your pages. 
If you are posting the results every time they go to the next page, then you will want to store them server side. If you have 1 giant Document Object Model, then you may wish to just hide and show different parts of the form. That way their settings will be stored in the DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the value of `q1` on the next page, you would use `$_POST['q1']`. You can verify that the element has been posted, and the value matches the specific radio button by using `if(isset($_POST['q1'])) && $_POST['q1'] == VALUE`. So your form code would look like -

```
  <input type="radio" name="q1" value="A" <?php if(isset($_POST['q1']) && ($_POST['q1'] == 'A')) echo 'checked="checked" ';?>/>
  A. <br />
  <input type="radio" name="q1" value="B" <?php if(isset($_POST['q1']) && ($_POST['q1'] == 'B')) echo 'checked="checked" ';?>/>
  B. <br />
  <input type="radio" name="q1" value="C" <?php if(isset($_POST['q1']) && ($_POST['q1'] == 'C')) echo 'checked="checked" ';?>/>
  C. <br />
  <input type="radio" name="q1" value="D" <?php if(isset($_POST['q1']) && ($_POST['q1'] == 'D')) echo 'checked="checked" ';?>/>
```