# radio button checked value to next page

Tags: php, html, input, radio-button

I have a the following form code:

```
<form method="post" action="nextpage">
<input type="radio" name="p" value="A"/>
<input type="radio" name="p" value="B"/>
<input type="radio" name="p" value="C"/>
<input type="radio" name="p" value="D"/>
</form>
```

The next page has to return the same form with the button checked.

this code: [PHP How to keep radio button state to the next page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18347175/php-how-to-keep-radio-button-state-to-the-next-page) didnt help.

Comment: What exactly do you want here? Explain it

Answer (score 1):

```
<form method="post" action="nextpage.php">
    <input type="radio" <?php if(isset($_POST['p'])) && $_POST['p'] == 'A') echo 'checked="checked" ';?> name="p" value="A"/>
//and so on for the rest....
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the below code:

```
<form method="post" action="nextpage">
   <input type="radio" name="p" value="A" <?php if(isset($_REQUEST['p']) && $_REQUEST['p'] == "A") echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>/>
   <input type="radio" name="p" value="B" <?php if(isset($_REQUEST['p']) && $_REQUEST['p'] == "B") echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>/>
   <input type="radio" name="p" value="C" <?php if(isset($_REQUEST['p']) && $_REQUEST['p'] == "C") echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>/>
   <input type="radio" name="p" value="D" <?php if(isset($_REQUEST['p']) && $_REQUEST['p'] == "D") echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>/>
</form>
```

on the next page right above code.

As in your example answer there is radio button with the name `q` and in your code name is `p` that is different in both code. Hope this will be your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="radio" <?=(isset($_REQUEST['p']) && $_REQUEST['p'] == 'A') ? 'checked="checked" ' : ''?> name="p" value="A" />
```